# Cursor con Update

Tags: oracle, plsql

Saludos desde Costa Rica,

Estoy iniciando con Oracle PL/SQL (cursando la carrera de sistemas) y quiero construir un cursor como práctica que actualice el registro de nombres, correos,  teléfonos y tarjetas de toda la base de datos.

La información de clientes está en 2 tablas solamente, ya logré sumar un 1 a la variable cada vez que el cursor encuentre un registro primero quiero intentar con nombres y después ingresar el resto de campos en el cursor, pero quiero diferenciarlo entre personas físicas(naturales) y jurídicas(sociedades) pero no logro hacer el update por lo que quisiera ver si puedes orientarme.

---

```
  declare 
  v_acum   number;

  cursor c_actualiza
  is
  select a.cod_cia, a.cod_docum,a.tip_docum, a.nom_tercero,  a.nom2_tercero, a.ape1_tercero,a.ape2_tercero,a.tlf_movil,
    b.tlf_numero, b.email,b.tlf_numero_com,b.email_com,b.cta_cte,b.txt_email,b.cod_tarjeta,b.num_tarjeta,
    b.fec_vcto_tarjeta
  from a1001399 a, a1001331 b
  where a.cod_cia = 1
    and a.nom_tercero != 'null'
    and a.tip_docum = b.tip_docum
    and a.cod_docum = b.cod_docum
    and a.cod_docum 
  in ('111810464',
  '111610631',
  '800870150',
  '110550726',
  '111830715',                 
  '111120585',
  '110030332',
  '111460930',
  '3101397485',
  '3101294479',                  
  '01002312815',
  '011203096',
  '012180004480193988',
  '011203096',
  '07469542');
  begin  

  v_acum := 0;

  for reg in c_actualiza loop

  v_acum := v_acum + 1;

      begin        

   UPDATE  a1001399 i
         SET i.nom_tercero = 'PRUEBASCR' || ' - ' || v_acum 
          where i.cod_cia = reg.cod_cia
           and i.tip_docum = reg.tip_docum
           and i.cod_docum = reg.cod_docum;
                 EXCEPTION                   
          when i.tip_docum  IN ( 'CJU' and 'EEX') then
            UPDATE  a1001399 i
         SET i.nom_tercero = 'DESARROLLOCR' || ' - ' || v_acum 
          where i.cod_cia = reg.cod_cia
           and i.tip_docum = reg.tip_docum
           and i.cod_docum = reg.cod_docum;

             --dbms_output.put_line('ERROR');

             END;


     dbms_output.put_line (reg.nom_tercero);

       end loop;

       end;
```

Comment: Hola. Bienvenido a StackOverflow. _no logro hacer el update_ no es la mejor descripción del problema que tienes. ¿hay algún mensaje de error? no hay error, pero el programa no se comporta como quisieras? qué es lo que hace? Te invito a leer [como preguntar](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hay cosas raras en tu código, como la palabra clave `EXCEPTION` que parece perdido en medio de tus updates, o la expresión `when i.tip_docum ...`, que también se ve un poco perdido. ¿Estás seguro que transcribistes bien el código?  Y siempre vale la pena esforzarse de formatear bien el código para que se pueda leer más fácilmente.

Answer (score 1):

Gracias, jachguate - sstan

Ya logré hacer que se actualizara un nombre y un apellido con un IF en los ID de clientes que seleccioné de muestra para no actualizar toda la base de datos hasta probar bien el código. Quisiera intentar lograr este mismo resultado con un "CASE"

declare

v_contador number;

cursor pruebas

is

```
select a.cod_cia,   ---compañía
       a.cod_docum, --identificacion del cliente
       a.tip_docum, --tipo físico o jurídico
       a.nom_tercero,
       a.nom2_tercero,
       a.ape1_tercero,
       a.ape2_tercero,
       a.tlf_movil,
       b.tlf_numero,
       b.email,
       b.tlf_numero_com,
       b.email_com,
       b.cta_cte,
       b.txt_email,
       b.cod_tarjeta,
       b.num_tarjeta,
       b.fec_vcto_tarjeta
  from a1001399 a, a1001331 b
 where a.cod_cia = b.cod_cia   -- índices de las 2 tablas
   and a.tip_docum = b.tip_docum --índices de las 2 tablas 
   and a.cod_docum = b.cod_docum  -- índices de las 2 tablas
   and a.cod_docum IN ('111810464',
                       '111610631',
                       '110550726',
                       '111830715',
                       '3101640433',
                       '3101124264',
                       '3101403163',
                       '0034300757',
                       '012180004480193988');
```

begin

v_contador := 0;

for reg in pruebas loop

```
v_contador := v_contador + 1;

update a1001399 x
   set x.nom_tercero  = 'PRUEBASCR' || '_' || v_contador,
       x.nom2_tercero = 'REGISTROS'
 where x.cod_cia = reg.cod_cia
   and x.cod_docum = reg.cod_docum
   and x.tip_docum = reg.tip_docum;
if reg.tip_docum = 'CJU' or reg.tip_docum = 'EEX' then
  update a1001399 x
     set x.nom_tercero  = 'DESARROLLOCR' || '_' || v_contador,
         x.nom2_tercero = 'REGISTROS'
   where x.cod_cia = reg.cod_cia
     and x.cod_docum = reg.cod_docum
     and x.tip_docum = reg.tip_docum;

end if;

commit;
```

end loop;

end;

---

El resultado obtenido.

Saludos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor utiliza el botón *Publica tu respuesta* solo para respuestas reales. Debes modificar tu pregunta original para añadir información adicional. Te invito a hacer el [tour] para aprender como funciona StackOverflow, y posteriormente borra esta no-respuesta.

Comment: Creo que tienes un error de lógica en tu SP, actualizas un registro, luego preguntas con un if y vuelves a actualizar el mismo registro... Debes poner tu operador lógico al principio (if X=Y then "haz esto" else "Haz lo otro") para no updatear dos veces el mismo registro.